# Read from stdin to new, named, file in vim

Tags: vim, stdin

I'd like to start vim on a non existing file, named **f**, with the content **c**. Both **f** and **c** are arbitrary and I'd like to not have to put anything in the vim config to fill new buffers with **c**.

Basically, I would like to combine

$ echo **c** | vim -

with

$ vim **f**

Is there a flag to vim which lets me achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
echo c | vim - +'w f'
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to automatically write the file to disk, but just set its name:  echo "c" | vim - +"file f"

Comment: Very good, thanks. @Heptite got what I really wanted, nice of you to comment. This is far my dirtiest Makefile target.. :)